# Manually update Quote Configurable Product

Tags: php, magento, quote, observers, configurable-product

I'm working on an module where i add a configurable product with its configured childs to the cart as (both) childs of an bundle product, through the event checkout_cart_product_add_after. In the observer I'm working with the quote item and the quote itself. here is my code

```
// $simple = is the simple product of the configurable
// $item = is the configurable item


$simple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simpleItem->getProduct()->getId());
$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($simple);
$parentItem = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

$item->setRowWeight($product->getWeight());

$quoteItem->setQuote($quote);
$quoteItem->setQty('1');

$quoteItem->setParentItem($parentItem);
$quoteItem->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice(0);

$quote->addItem($quoteItem);
$quote->save();
```

Now if i adding the product with different configuration & same parent product to cart i want to update the the two products with the new one. Currently magento is adding 2 new rows on the quote item table. I tried with quote **updateItem()** function but i get an error message.

At this point im running out of knowledge and need some help to achieve the task. Here is the screenshot of the cart. Thanks!

[image]